# jQuery 1.8.1 - live, livequery, on + change not working

Tags: jquery, firefox, live, livequery

My code is:

```
jQuery('#s_valor').on('change', function () {
    alert('Help mee!!');
});
```

The '#s_valor' is loaded (jQuery.load), and this works on Opera, but not on Firefox 15. I'm using Ubuntu and I've tried live(), on() and livequery(), no one worked on Firefox 15.

Someone have a tip to me ? (Sorry my bad english, I'm brazilian)

Comment: ... what is "#s_valor", radio button by any chance? Then you'll need to use 'click' instead of change.

Answer (score 2):

When you load an element dynamically you need to use `.on()` with an element already in the DOM. Usually the worst case is the body element. For example:

```
jQuery('body').on('change', '#s_valor', function () {
    alert('Help mee!!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you enclose it in document. Ready function..
Also place an alert inside it and check whether the jQuery file is correctly associated with your page..

```
$(function() {
   jQuery('#s_valor').on('change', function () {
      alert('Help mee!!');
   });
});
```

Comment: The code is in the right place...I've other functionalities that work, only this event not work...

Comment: What exactly is the #s_valor element

Comment: "#s_valor" is an input text element

Comment: So why don't you bind the event immediately after the element is created. Look's like you are binding the event even before the element is available in the markup

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).on('click', 'p', $.noop);`

or even

`$(document).delegate('p', 'click', $.noop);`

http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/33